# Replace only first three occurence using PHP

Tags: php

I need to replace only the first three matches from a string with another string

```
$strings = "Apple Orange Mango Orange Grapes Apple Orange Banana Orange Dates Orange";
```

it should be output like :

```
Apple Strawberry Mango Strawberry Grapes Apple Strawberry Banana Orange Dates Orange
```

I have tried

```
$strings  = str_replace("Orange", "Strawberry", $strings);
```

but it replaces all occurrences in the string.

Comment: mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )

Comment: http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: thanks anyway I will try all suggestion

Comment: @DivyeshPatoriya `str_replace` won't work here, as `$count` is reference argument, and will return how many replacements it has done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use preg_replace for this ,

```
$strings    = "Apple Orange Mango Orange Grapes Apple Orange Banana Orange Dates Orange";
$strings    = preg_replace("/Orange/","Strawberry",$strings,3);
echo $strings;
```

It will output as you wish

Comment: str_replace goes hand in hand with the same functionality, but <3 regex